# Weird Rails URL issue when rendering a new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am rendering a new action but somehow getting the "index" URL.  To be more specific, my create action looks like this:

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @listing = Listing.new(params[:listing])
        @listing.user = @current_user

        if @listing.save
          redirect_to @listing
        else
          flash[:error] = "There were errors"
          render :action => "new"
        end
      end
end
```

When there are errors, I get the "new" action but my URL is the index URL - http://domain.com/listings

Anyone know why this would happen?  My routes file is fairly standard:

```
map.connect 'listings/send_message', :controller => 'listings', :action => 'send_message'
  map.resources :listings
map.root :controller => "listings"
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you render you just get the content that will be returned to the browser as the response body. `On Rendering your url is not get changed.`

Best example of that create a scaffold application.so when you submit the form on the new and error occurs your 'new.html.erb' is displayed but   your url shows `domain_name/controller_name/create`

Hope that helps :)